# How can I add different meta open graphs for homepage and single product pages?

Tags: magento2, product-page, home-page, meta, open-graph

When I post the link of my site on facebook, the image added was 2 images, logo and other one. Facebook displayed the first ones. So I needed to add in `default_head_block.xml file (app/design/frontend/Venustheme/kasitoo/Magento_Theme/layout)`

the following code:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Sitename" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description site lorem ipsum" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://sitename.ro/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MyOrganic" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://sitename/pub/media/facebook.jpg" />
```

The problem is that this overrides the meta open graphs from single product page. That are located in

```
general.phtml in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/opengraph

<meta property="og:type" content="og:product" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProduct()->getName()); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getImage($block->getProduct(), 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl()); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProduct()->getShortDescription()); ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getProduct()->getProductUrl()); ?>" />
<?php if ($priceAmount = $block->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()):?>
    <meta property="product:price:amount" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $priceAmount; ?>"/>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('meta.currency'); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Where should I add the metas for homepage, in order to work properly the metas for single product pages??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meta tags can be added to a `cms_index_index.xml` layout file the same way as you added them to the `default_head_block.xml` file and they will then only apply on the homepage.

Example -

default_head_block.xml -

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/DEFAULTIMAGE.png" />
</head>
```

cms_index_index.xml -

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/HOMEPAGEIMAGE.png" />
</head>
```

Will result in the `og:image` property being `DEFAULTIMAGE.png` on every page without an image explicitly set, and `HOMEPAGEIMAGE.png` on the home page.

Comment: It is necessary to verify our site after add meta ?

Answer (score 1):

OG Meta tags can be added to layout file of default_head_block.xml file and they will be apply on the All Pages.

```
<head>

    <meta name="og:title" content="Printing coop is a most famous Digital Printing certer"/>
    <meta name="og:description" content="Printing coop is a most famous Digital Printing certer in Montreal Canada.Professional Printer Services."/>

</head>
```

Comment: For home page okay, what about remaing page like product page. here we manually put title what about 50k products.

Comment: You need to add catalog category XML and catalog product XML files

Comment: can you pls explain how to add for category and product, as you know home page we put direct content, for category and products it is get dynamically right?

Answer (score 0):

On my projects, I use [Magento 2 Open Graph](https://magefan.com/magento-2-open-graph-extension-og-tags) by Magefan. This module allows to manage OG tags for:

- Homepage
- Product
- Any CMS Page
- Catalog Category
- Blog Homepage
- Blog Category
- Blog Post

So using Magento 2 admin panel I can upload a new OG image at any time as well as change the OG description or title.